# Using first row in Pandas groupby dataframe to calculate cumulative difference

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following grouped dataframe based on daily data

```
Studentid  Year Month BookLevel

 JSmith    2015  12    1.4
           2016   1    1.6
                  2    1.8
                  3    1.2
                  4    2.0

 MBrown    2016   1    3.0        
                  2    3.2
                  3    3.6
```

I want to calculate the difference from the starting point in BookLevel for each Studentid. The current BookLevel is a .max calculation from the GroupBy to get the highest bookLevel for each month for each student

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
 Studentid    Year   Month   BookLevel    Progress Since Start

  JSmith      2015     12       1.4         0 (or NAN)
              2016      1       1.6        .2
                        2       1.8        .4
                        3       1.2       -.2
                        4       2.0        .6

              2016      1       3.0         0 (or NAN)   
  MBrown                2       3.2        .2
                        3       3.6        .6
```

I'm new to Python/Pandas and have tried a number of things and nothing comes close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, this should work, if we `groupby` on the first level and subtract BookLevel from the series returned by calling `transform` with `first` then we can add this as the new desired column:

```
In [47]:
df['ProgressSinceStart'] = df['BookLevel'] - df.groupby(level='Studentid')['BookLevel'].transform('first')
df

Out[47]:
                      BookLevel  ProgressSinceStart
Studentid Year Month                               
JSmith    2015 12           1.4                 0.0
          2016 1            1.6                 0.2
               2            1.8                 0.4
               3            1.2                -0.2
               4            2.0                 0.6
MBrown    2016 1            3.0                 0.0
               2            3.2                 0.2
               3            3.6                 0.6
```

Comment: Thanks..... I was looking for the delta to the first data point for each student, not the delta to the previous data point in one step...but I should be able to use a cum calc to get the number I need. I'm curious why did your calc restart at zero on the last data point of JSmith, not the first datapoint of MBrown?

Comment: OK, I understand what you want now, see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite know how to copy dataframe with multiple index. So I just form my own. FYI: it will be great you put the raw `dataframe` so I can just use `pd.read_clipboard()`. Below is how I form the df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BookLevel': [1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0, 3.2, 3.6],
 'Month': [12,1,2,3,4,1,2,3],
 'Studentid': ['JSmith']*5 + ['MBrown']*3,
 'Year': [2015]+[2016]*7})

df = df.set_index(['Studentid', 'Year', 'Month'])
```

**Solution:**

Here I use `Multiindex Groupby` with `given level=0` for group, and then use `diff` to find the difference of consecutive rows and followed by `cumsum` to find the cumulative sum of the difference:

```
rslt = pd.concat([v.diff().cumsum() for n, v in df.groupby(level=0)])
```

**Output:**

```
rslt
Out[151]: 
                      BookLevel
Studentid Year Month           
JSmith    2015 12           NaN
          2016 1            0.2
               2            0.4
               3           -0.2
               4            0.6
MBrown    2016 1            NaN
               2            0.2
               3            0.6
```

If want to make the final df exactly as what you shown, just do following formatting:

```
rslt.columns=['ProgressSinceStart']
rslt['BookLevel']=df['BookLevel']
```

**Output:**

```
rslt
Out[153]: 
                      ProgressSinceStart  BookLevel
Studentid Year Month                               
JSmith    2015 12                    NaN        1.4
          2016 1                     0.2        1.6
               2                     0.4        1.8
               3                    -0.2        1.2
               4                     0.6        2.0
MBrown    2016 1                     NaN        3.0
               2                     0.2        3.2
               3                     0.6        3.6
```